# What are the most appropriate statistics to calculate using this reliability data?

Tags: reliability, calibration

10 teachers independently look at 3 randomly selected papers from a previous edition of a subject, and gives each a mark out of 100. The 3 papers will be the same across all markers.

I am meant to prepare a report so that the teachers can calibrate themselves to be more consistent. What statistics are most appropriate for me to include in such a report?

Comment: How many papers do they examine? a few? some tens? a hundred? I think a reasonable answer will depend on that.  But, you could use analysis of variance to test the hypothesis of equal means ... that could be a start.

Comment: Each teacher examines 3 papers during this practice marking phase. Then during the real marking phase they will examine 50-90 papers each. Could you explain how the number of papers affects things?

Comment: With $n=3$ for each group (ten groups, defined by the ten teachers) what more can you do than computing means and plotting parallell stripcharts (dotplots) for the groups? Computing variances for $n=3$ do not make much sense .... a formal anova will have very low power.    You should really try to sample a few more than 3 papers for this initial test!

Comment: I'd earlier posted a question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169747/which-of-these-forms-of-data-should-i-choose-to-calibrate-markers-of-differing-g to ask what sort of data would be best, but got no response. However, there is a limited budget to pay the teachers to do extra work of this sort. Computing means and plotting dotplots on n=3 may still be of some use.

Comment: At least it would enable you to see is one teacher is a clear outlier .... increasing even only to $n=5$ or $n=6$ would make some more formal methods feasible.

Comment: Could you describe what formal methods would be feasible with n=5 or n=6, besides ANOVA which you already mentioned? Or should I create a separate question for that?

Comment: parallell dotplots, some nonparametric alternative to ANOVA

Answer (score 1):

Format the data into a matrix such that each row corresponds to a single test and each column corresponds to a single teacher. You can then calculate the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC). If you want to see how interchangeable these teachers are, you should use the single score absolute agreement formulation of the ICC (SPSS calls this the two-way random single measures model for absolute agreement). I would present this point estimate along with a confidence interval. With only 3 tests, the interval will be quite wide.